# Python to extract unique CSV rows

Tags: python, csv, set, unique

I'm trying to get the first occurrences of each row of a CSV in Python. However, I'm facing an issue. My CSV files looks like this:

```
1,2,3,a,7,5,y,0
1,2,3,a,3,5,y,8
1,2,3,a,5,3,y,7
1,2,3,d,7,5,n,0
1,2,3,d,3,5,n,8
1,2,3,d,5,3,n,7
2,3,4,f,4,6,y,9
2,3,4,f,5,6,y,9
2,3,4,f,7,3,y,9
2,3,4,e,3,5,n,9
2,3,4,e,0,7,n,9
2,3,4,e,5,8,n,9
```

I tried this way to get the first occurrences of unique values based on one of the columns.

```
def unique():
    rows = list(csv.reader(open('try.csv', 'r'), delimiter=','))
    columns = zip(*rows)
    uniq = set(columns[1])

    indexed = defaultdict(list)

    for x in uniq:
        i = columns[1].index(x)
        indexed[i] = rows[i]

    return indexed
```

It works fine for one unique column value set. However,

1. I'd like to set columns[1] and columns[6] as unique values.
2. The tricky part is columns[6] is always y or n. If I set that, it returns me only first y and n columns. I'd like to get all the columns that have both columns[1] and columns[6] as unique. For every columns[2] value, I need the first occurrence of y and n rows. Sorry for my poor description. So basically, I'd like my output to be like:

> ```
> 1,2,3,d,7,5,n,0,a
> 2,3,4,e,3,5,n,9,f
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some room for improvement in your code, but I didn't want to rewrite it in depth, as you had it *almost* right. The "key" point is that you need a *compound key*. This is the *pair* `(r[1],r[6])` that has to be unique. In addition, I took the liberty to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for fast-lookup, but preserving the row order.

```
import csv
import collections

def unique():
    rows = list(csv.reader(open('try.csv', 'r'), delimiter=','))
    result = collections.OrderedDict()
    for r in rows:
        key = (r[1],r[6])  ## The pair (r[1],r[6]) must be unique
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = r

    return result.values()

from pprint import pprint
pprint(unique())
```

Producing:

```
[['1', '2', '3', 'a', '7', '5', 'y', '0'],
 ['1', '2', '3', 'a', '7', '5', 'n', '0'],
 ['2', '3', '4', 'f', '4', '6', 'y', '9'],
 ['2', '3', '4', 'f', '3', '5', 'n', '9']]
```

---

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can get the modified desired output? I'm able to get just the columns with "n" in columns[6], but I'm unable to get the last column from columns[6]=y

Comment: @abn The quick and dirty hack is to replace `if key not in result:` by `if key not in result and r[6] == 'n':`. If you have other changes, please ask _an other question_.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate implementation.

Each row is read in from the data set.  We use a `defaultdict(list)` to store all rows, based on each rows two-column index. As a row is read in from the dataset, it's appended to the `defaultdict` based on that row's two-column index key.

At the end, we scan through the `defaultdict`. We want the *first* row from the dataset that matched the index, so we return `uniq[0]` that corresponds to the two-column index.

### source

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
def unique():
    uniq = defaultdict(list)
    for row in csv.reader(open('try.csv', 'r'), delimiter=','):
        uniq[ (row[0],row[6]) ].append(row)

    for idx,row in uniq.iteritems():
        yield row[0]

print list( unique() )
```

### output

```
[['2', '3', '4', 'f', '4', '6', 'y', '9'], ['2', '3', '4', 'f', '3', '5', 'n', '9'], ['1', '2', '3', 'a', '7', '5', 'y', '0'], ['1', '2', '3', 'a', '7', '5', 'n', '0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but could be useful for other: why not call the external `uniq` command if you are in a Unix environment? That way you would not have to reinvent this code and would benefit from a potentially better performance.